# Capture frames from both cameras (TelePhoto and WideAngle) in the same time

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturedevice

It's possible to get frame from [TelephotoCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype/2361478-builtintelephotocamera), [WideAngleCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype/2361449-builtinwideanglecamera) or [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499418/3226984) using [DualCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype/2727142-builtindualcamera):

```
//auto
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
//telephoto
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTelephotoCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
//wideAngle
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
```

But how to get frames from [TelephotoCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype/2361478-builtintelephotocamera) and [WideAngleCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype/2361449-builtinwideanglecamera) in the same time (using devices with [dual camera](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH107-SW32)s).

---

**Edit1**
Tried to add 2 inputs to [capture session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession):

```
captureSession?.addInput(input)
captureSession?.addInput(input2)

NSInvalidArgumentException: Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported
```

<s>**Edit2**</s>
<s>Tried to enable [isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/2873917-isdualcameradualphotodeliveryena) flag for [capture photo output](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput):</s>

<s>`capturePhotoOutput?.isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled = true`</s>

<s>`NSInvalidArgumentException: Dual Camera dual photo delivery is not supported in this configuration`</s>
**But**
[isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliverySupported](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/2890245-isdualcameradualphotodeliverysup) gives `false` on `iPhone 8 Plus`
could it be the reason of my problem?

---

Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
Just pick the right configuration.

---

Capture device should be `builtInDualCamera`:

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
```

---

Configure capture photo output after configuring capture session:

```
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
captureSession?.addInput(input)
captureSession?.addOutput(capturePhotoOutput!)

capturePhotoOutput?.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
```

**`capturePhotoOutput?.isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled = true`**

---

Configure photo settings before capture the photo:

```
let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
photoSettings.isAutoDualCameraFusionEnabled = false
```

**`photoSettings.isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled = true`**

---

Implement `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`, and override next method:

```
public func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)
```

---

You will receive 2 `photoOutput` callbacks!

Comment: I have an iPhone 7 plus but capturePhotoOutput.isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliverySupported is returning false, and if i ignore this and just set to true, it will crash with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput setDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled:] Dual Camera dual photo delivery is not supported in this configuration'. Any idea is what else need to be configured? i believe 7plus can take dual photos

Comment: @kawingkelvin have you checked [this option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/2890245-isdualcameradualphotodeliverysup)?